# Zsh can't find terminal definitions on Mac

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, macos, xterm

Perhaps it's from updating Brew (I use Homebrew **Bash** and **Zsh** on Mac), but Zsh can no longer find **xterm** definitions.
For instance, in my `.zshrc` file I have the following:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

This always worked properly up until today. Now the command line responds with:

```
zsh: can't find terminal definition for xterm-256color
```

I tried exporting `TERM` manually, setting different definitions (`export TERM=xterm` etc.) and reinstalling **Zsh** with no luck. All native terminal definitions are not found. Interestingly, this is not a problem in other shells (**Bash**, etc). It's just in **Zsh**.

If I comment out the export in `.zshrc`, Kitty still works normally because it uses its own `xterm-kitty`, but the basic Terminal is totally broken (no color, unusable key bindings).

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: A couple of possibilities: you may have set `TERMINFO` to point to the terminal database used in Brew, or you might have installed a `zsh` from Brew.  (more likely the former, especially if Brew uses a different pathname convention than MacOS).

Answer (score 4):

Turns out `TERMINFO` is not set in my environmental variables. A fix for now is to add this to my `.zshrc` file:

```
export TERMINFO='/usr/share/terminfo/'
```

This doesn't explain why it is not set anymore, but it works for now. Thanks to @ThomasDickey for the help!